# Stripe: Is it possible to create a direct charge with idempotency

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, idempotent

I ma trying to make a direct charge to a stripe connected account and I am able to do it with the following

```
const charge = {
  amount,
  currency,
  source} ;

return stripe.charges.create(
  charge ,
  {stripe_account: stripeVendorAccount});
```

Question: is there a way to include an idempotency option to the charge object? If not, what is the best way to avoid duplicate charges?

I tried this but it does not work

```
const charge = {
  amount,
  currency,
  source} ;

return stripe.charges.create(
  charge ,
  {stripe_account: stripeVendorAccount},
  {idempotency_key });
```

**EDIT**: this is my function

```
exports.stripeCharge = functions.database
                                .ref('/payments/{userId}/{paymentId}')
                                .onWrite( (change,context) => {
const payment = change.after.val();
const userId = context.params.userId;
const paymentId = context.params.paymentId;
const stripeVendorAccount = 'xx'
// checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
if (!payment || payment.charge) return;
return admin.database()
              .ref(`/users/${userId}`)
              .once('value')
              .then(snapshot => {
return snapshot.val();
               })
               .then(async customer => {
const amount = payment.amount;
const idempotency_key = paymentId;  // prevent duplicate charges
const source = payment.token.id;
const currency = payment.currency;
const application_fee = payment.application_fee;
const description = payment.description;



//-------- destination charges
// const transfer_data = {destination: stripeVendorAccount};
// const charge = {
//   amount,
//   currency,
//   description,
//   transfer_data,
//   source};
// return stripe.charges.create(charge , { idempotency_key });
//                })
//                .then(charge => {
// admin.database()
//                         .ref(`/payments/${userId}/${paymentId}/charge`)
//                         .set(charge);
//                         return true;
//                   })
//-------- destination charges

//-------- DIRECT charges
const charge = {
  amount,
  currency,
  description,
  application_fee,
  source} ;

return stripe.charges.create(charge ,{stripe_account: stripeVendorAccount});
               })
               .then(charge => {
admin.database()
                        .ref(`/payments/${userId}/${paymentId}/charge`)
                        .set(charge);
                        return true;
                  })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i guess the creation of a charge isn't idempotent by definition, since a charge is usually connected to a single purchase. (If a user initiates the purchase of the same item three times in a row, it will result in three different orders/charges).
I don't know your current implementation of the business logic behind your e-commerce integration. But if you just want to avoid to create multiple charges for a single order you should identify your orders with an unique id and persist it in a database. In your charge method query from the database if there is already a charge for that purchase, if not create one.

Comment: I just would like to avoid that  multiple POST requests on this resources will not change result - in other words, to prevent duplicate charges to the card. I have posted my code where you can see I am passing the paymentId as idempotency object in case of destination charge however I ma not able to do the same for direct charges since charge accept only one option object and I must pass the stripeId